# Why AMP Symbol is not displayed in Mobile search?

Tags: amp-html

I have converted the blog in AMP version for desktop & Mobile websites. There is not any non-amp version of the blog.  I only have one page, and that page is an AMP page, so I added the canonical link to it, which will then simply point to itself as mentioned here https://www.ampproject.org/docs/fundamentals/discovery:

i.e link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/blog/post"

My amp blogs are validated and AMP passed. But I can't see AMP symbol in the mobile search. Can you please help me regarding it? Here is one post URL - https://www.aussizzgroup.com/blog/mistakes-you-must-avoid-when-buying-oshc-or-ovhc-policy if you would like to check the AMP code. Awaiting your warm reply.

Thanks

Comment: Try to type exact match of your post title.. I check in my mobile browser it shows amp symbol

Comment: Thanks Bachcha singh for your reply.. I saw the screenshot seny by you. But when I am looking on my phone with exact post title as how you suggested, I can't see the AMP symbol. Also, I wanted to confirm that I have uploaded the right canonical tags? Is everything looks fine regarding AMP on my website? I appreciate your help.

Comment: at least two users has amp screenshot for your page, i think it means that from our side everything is fine. you may check it with another phone or browser..

Answer (score 0):

Your site appears as AMP valid for me (see screenshot below). Google sometimes chooses not to serve up the site through the AMP cache for whatever reason. I know for my site, which has been AMP'd for almost 6 months so it's definitely in their cache, if I Google the exact site/company name it does not serve it up through AMP. However, if I Google a page title it hits me with the AMP cached version.

[Screenshot from my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVNEI.png)

Also, may be an obvious thing and I see your blog post is showing as 3 days old in the search results, but data propagation can take time. The server that serves the AMP cache version near you may not have received the data yet.

Comment: Thanks Craig for your reply.. I saw the screenshot sent by you. But when I am looking on my phone with exact post title. I can't see the AMP symbol with the blogs. I have also tried to check with the query like site:aussizzgroup.com/blogs, but I couldn't see the AMP symbol. Might be it will take some time to display. Also, I wanted to confirm that I have uploaded the right canonical tags? Is everything looks fine regarding AMP on my website? I appreciate your help. Thanks mate. :-)

Comment: Trying hitting this link: https://www.google.ca/amp/s/www.aussizzgroup.com/blog/mistakes-you-must-avoid-when-buying-oshc-or-ovhc-policy. That's your AMP cache link (they all start with https://www.google.ca/amp/s/). If that works for you then you're good. If that link doesn't work for you it's most definitely a propagation thing - Google just hasn't hit the server near you with the AMP cache. I'd check into it more but I'm on my phone and am currently holding my sleeping baby while my wife is out and hoping not to wake him haha.

Comment: Obviously replace .ca with your local Google TLD if it doesn't automatically do it